# Make phantomjs (nodejs system) use local fonts instead of webfonts

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I ran into the problem of rendering very large pdf files from html with phantomjs 2.1.1

The mentioned solution was to install fonts locally on ubuntu & then have phantomjs use these.

Does anybody have experience doing this?

Comment: Did you install all the font packages, see here... https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620

Answer (score 2):

You should install the `libfreetype6`, `libfreetype6-dev`, `libfontconfig1` and `libfontconfig1-dev` packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev -y
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev -y
```

You may also need to set the following value in your bash profile:

`LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`